# UIWebView loads first HTTPS page fine, but fails when opening a link

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, https, uiwebview

I'm trying to create an iOS wrapper for my web app so my users can access it on the app store and receive push notifications. I've successfully got the front page of the app loaded and displayed over HTTPS, but once I click on the login button, which uses Facebook for authentication, nothing appears to happen on the screen and the log in Xcode shows this error

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

This is kind of confusing because the login works just fine in mobile safari, and we've got a real HTTPS cert (little green lock icon and everything!).

Am I just missing some crucial step in setting up my UIWebView to handle opening links?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

As of iOS 9, App Transport Security requires that if your app needs to communicate securely with remote servers, then they need to be whitelisted.